# Synching select rows from an Excel spreadsheet into a SharePoint 2013 List?

Tags: 2013, excel, sync

I know you can connect Excel and SharePoint 2013, but is there a way to "selectively" sync data from an Excel Spreadsheet into a SharePoint List?

Basically, we have a master spreadsheet where each row contains details about a project. We want to start putting this information into a SharePoint list, but not all projects should be shared. Is there a way to create a column where if the value in that column is "yes" then that entire project row is synced with the corresponding project item in a SharePoint list? (or some other way to accomplish what I am trying to do?)

So SharePoint would have the select items, Excel would have all of them, and both would stay synced so they display the same information.

I have some JavaScript skills and I could be up for trying to use PowerShell or some other program if it works!

I hope that makes sense and thank you for your help!!